# jQuery Cookie and Variables

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm currently using jQuery cookie for a button

```
$('.vote').one('click', function(){      
    var cookieid = ($(this).data("id")); //cookie name
    alert ($.cookie(cookieid));  //..etc
```

This gives me a textbox saying "undefined".  However, I do know that the variable `cookieid` is assigned, as alerting the variable gives me a value.

Furthermore, this script works fine if I use a 'cookieid' that I know I have assigned.  For instance, I have a cookie named `17`.  When I `alert ($.cookie('17'));` everything works correctly.

I'm pretty sure the problem is not in my end of the code, so can jQuery cookie not handle variables?

Edit:

```
//creating cookie if none already exists
var cookieid = ($(this).data("id")); //cookie name
        if ($.cookie(cookieid) == 'active') //if cookie exists
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            $.cookie(cookieid, 'active');
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`($(this).data("id"))` returns a number.

```
alert(typeof $(this).data("id")); //number
```

Try converting it to a string:

```
alert ($.cookie(cookieid.toString()));
```

Here's a working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ULMe/)

Comment: Hmm, does converting the cookie to a string only necessary for alerts?  I was just using an alert for the example, and maybe that's the only place it wasn't working.  I've edited the post with additional info on how I'm using this.

Comment: this.data('id') returns a number if your data attribute value is a number, but it will return a string if the value was string. I guess this is why it wasn't working.